# bypass jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery validation. I have two elements in my form that submit the form, one being the submit button, the other a dropdown menu which I need to submit the form so that I can populate another dropdown box. It is essential that my dropdown box submits the form, but I was wondering if I can get it to bypass the validation step of form submission?

Thanks

PS: I've tried class="cancel" which only seems to work on buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in ignore statement for this:

```
$("#yourform").validate({
    ignore: ".element_to_ignore"
});
```

Here´s the link to the manual: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

Comment: this is not really bypassing - this is specifying attributes to ignore. unless you want to `addClass('element_to_ignore')` to everything this isn't really a solution